# How to use multiple conditions in one locator?

Tags: python, playwright

One of several buttons may appear on the page, I have to wait for the first one and perform the action, with Selenium I did it this way:

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    lambda driver: \
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Confirm") or \
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Edit") or \
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Submit")
)
```

Is there any equivalent at playwright?

Comment: CSS selectors let you use an _or_ semantic with a `,` operator. If you're getting by text, regex also has alternation. Worst case scenario, there's `Promise.race` or `Promise.allSettled`. There are other ways, but it depends on your actual use case, which hasn't been shared, so there's not much ground for making an accurate recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't figured it out how to do this natively with Playwright but in js you can use

```
await Promise.race([selector1, slector2, selector3])
```

and the test will proceed with the first one that resolves. Probably you can adopt a similar concept in python with

```
asyncio.wait(selectors_set, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```